# How to center two square blocks in page?

Tags: html, css, styling

I have a page where I'm displaying the status of two websites -- as in if they're currently up and running, or not. If the site is up, I want the block to have a light green background, and if not, a light red one. And the site's name should be centered inside the block.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

```css
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #container {
      width: 800px;
      height: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    #smallcontainer {
      width: 208px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 200px auto auto;
    }
    .status {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background: #efefef;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 2px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="smallcontainer">
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="status"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works (see [full screen output](https://jsfiddle.net/hk09ffp4/embedded/result/)), but I feel like I'm way off. How do I do something simple as this using CSS, the *correct* way? I feel like my code is a hack. And how would you write the text exactly in the center of the block, vertically and horizontally?

And is it possible to have it such a way that it works across all desktop screen sizes? Maybe I should specify width and height in percentage as opposed to pixels?

Comment: Rather than using float: left, I would use display: inline-block

Comment: @kojow7: Okay. You mean otherwise the code is fine?

Comment: I am not an expert here, so cannot answer best practices. One thing I might change is the margin-left: 2px to "margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px". This will center it a bit better (it won't really be noticeable, but little things like this bother me). :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qtyp8mbs/

Comment: **Note**: The smallcontainer etc. are used just to get it to work. I don't actually need those unless they're required for this to work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). <sub><sup>[support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)</sup></sub>

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="status"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.status {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #efefef;
    margin-left: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/b9n3h1en/**

Comment: Finally, someone understands! Thank you. Flexbox looks interesting, I'll check it out.

Comment: For the text align, I'm using this `span { position: relative; top: 40%; transform: translateY(-50%); }`. [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/b9n3h1en/1/). Is that fine or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Alright, I'm dumb! Thank you again! Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hk09ffp4/2/), aligned text vertically and horizontally in center of the div.

```
body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #container {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px  solid #ccc;
    }
    #smallcontainer {
        width: 208px;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 200px auto auto;
    }
    .status {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: #efefef;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: Positioning the text isn't the main problem. I want to know how to position the blocks correctly. I'm certain the code I've posted is a *way* way off from how it *should* be done. Could you show me how it should be done?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyk0kt4w/)

```
body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;

      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
    }
    #smallcontainer {
      width: 208px;
      height: 100px;
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      margin-left:-100px;
      margin-top:-50px;
    }
    .status {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: #efefef;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;

        display: -moz-box;
        -moz-box-orient: vertical;
        -moz-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;

        display: box;
        box-orient: vertical;
        box-pack: center;
        box-align: center; 
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Also see more about "display:flexbox"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="smallcontainer">
        <div class="status">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="txt">Text Here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
            <div class="border">
                <div class="txt">More Text Here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container {
    width: 95%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
#smallcontainer {
    width: 208px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.status {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
}
.border {
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.txt {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bootsified/kf7Lbq24/

Answer (score 0):

You can add negative margins to each of the `div`s you want to put exactly in the center. Note that for this the width and height should be in pixels.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  margin-top: -300px;
}
#smallcontainer {
  width: 208px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -104px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.status {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #efefef;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="smallcontainer">
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="status"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```